# Search and remove floating numbers in scientific form using REGEX and SED

Tags: sed

I was working on a solution using shell script (bash) to search floating numbers with exponent reaching more than 3 digits (ex. 11.1234567e+300) and remove e+ and the digits after e+.

I was using grep to search for it but im having trouble applying it in SED.

```
grep -E '([[:digit:]]+[.])[[:digit:]]+[eE][+-][[:digit:]]{3}' filename
```

Sample data would be something like below.

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
TEXT123,11.12345,12.12345e+300,13.123456
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what's the exected output?

Comment: this should be the expected output.

COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
TEXT123,11.12345,12.12345,13.123456

Comment: Include the expected output and all other relevant information in your question, don't spread it out in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, and you want to search and replace the `e+/-[[:digits:]]{3}` with nothing, you could use:

```
sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+)[eE][+-][[:digit:]]{3}/\1/g' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+)[eE][+-][[:digit:]]{3}/\1/g' file
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
TEXT123,11.12345,12.12345,13.123456
```

Let me know if this is what you intended and if not, I'm happy to help further.

[@TimurShtatland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967621/timur-shtatland) brings up a good point. If your intent was to keep the `[Ee][+-]` as the plain reading of your question indicates, you could use:

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+[eE][+-])[[:digit:]]{3}/\1/;ta' file
```

(though I'm not sure what purpose leaving the `[Ee][+-]` would serve)

Comment: This is a very simple solution and it worked! thanks for helping! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{\b ( \d+ [.]? \d* ) [Ee] [-+]? \d{3,} }{$1}xg' in_file > out_file
```

For example:

```
echo 'TEXT123,11.12345,12.12345e+300,13.123456' | perl -pe 's{\b ( \d+ [.]? \d* ) [Ee] [-+]? \d{3,} }{$1}xg'
```

Output:

```
TEXT123,11.12345,12.12345,13.123456
```

Comment: Yep, that matches the "leave the `e+/-`" variety too. I was a bit unclear whether and why that would be wanted, but that is the plain reading of the question.

Comment: sorry ill be editing it.. it should remove all digits after e+- including the e+-.

Comment: @jgpadilla04 Updated the answer.